# the difference between GLM and fisher's exact test

Tags: regression, logistic, fishers-exact-test

I want to compare the enrichment or overlapping between 2 lists.  I found some paper use fisher's exact test, or other papers use GLM (logistic regression).

Does anyone know what the difference between two methods aforementioned is?

Comment: Use Logistic regression with a continuous independent variable with a binary output.  Otherwise when the independent variable is discrete, I find the Fisher's exact test easier to understand and explain.